# Can't get the contents between <script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain

I have a page http://www.a.com/hello  which will return a JSON, now I want to get it in http://www.b.com I tried several cross-domain-ajax method, but none of them worked:
1. I have no control over `a.com`(though I trust it, so don't worry about XSS)
2. to access `a.com/hello`, cookie/session are needed, so I can't use a proxy on `b.com`.
Then I turn my eyes to other method, I notice that `img, script, iframe` can get contents cross domain, so I try to use them to load the content:
1. iframe: I can see the content in iframe, but I can't get it from js due to same-origin-policy.
2. img: Can't see the content.
3. script: I can see that content is loaded and evaluated, but when I try to get the contents between the `<script>` using `innerHTML`, I got nothing.

My question is, how to do the `3`rd method above? or is there other ways that could solve my problem?
The content of what http://www.a.com/hello is like:

```
 {"candidate":[{"id":251574647,"name":"\u5f20\u6f47"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not directly the access the contents of a script element in the page. To be able to do what you want you will have to use JSONP or have the output of your script set/update a specific variable.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP